# C++ Загрузки статической библиотеки.

Tags: c++

Добрый день я являюсь новичком в области C++ и тут возникла интересная проблема совместимости новых библиотек со старыми ОС. Например есть некий код который использует типы из `dxgi.lib`, например

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "dxgi.h"

int main()
{
    DXGI_SURFACE_DESC surface;
    return 0;
}
```

.exe cкомпилированый  с помощью Toolset v90, будет работать на всех ОС Windows где будет найдена соответствующая библиотека. Но например при попытке запуска этого .exe на Windows Vista, будет выдана соответствующая ошибка.

> Не найдено dxgi.dll.

Почему .dll? Я могу ошибаться но из информации в интернете dxgi.lib это вроде бы как статическая заглушка для динамической версии dxgi.dll.

`Возможно ли в коде как-то проверять что данная библиотека с данным типом не доступна, и уже например использовать другую библиотеку.` С динамической библиотекой вроде бы более менее понятно, но что делать со статической заглушкой к динамической библиотеке. К тому же нет возможности изменять dxgi.lib и dxgi.dll тоже.

Comment: Вы хотите сказать что ваше приложение, использующее интерфейс `dxgi` будет работать на `Windows XP`?

Comment: @LLENN, хотелось бы запускать приложение под Windows XP например, но не обеспечивать работу функционала которое использует типы из dxgi.lib.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша проблема возможно связана с самой операционной системой на которой вы запускаете ваше приложение.

В документации к `DXGI` говорится о том что [минимальной поддерживаемой версией является `Windows Vista`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/desktop/direct3ddxgi/dx-graphics-dxgi), но не говорится о сервис паках или еще какой либо дополнительной информации.

---

*Дополнение к комментарию.*

Вам необходимо будет описать интерфейс посредник, для динамической загрузки, без использования статической линковки основного приложения с описанным интерфейсом. Далее динамически ее подгружать и работать с `DXGI` именно через этот интерфейс.

Псевдокод:

```
if(CheckDXGISuppport())
{
    LoadLibrary("my_super_dxgi_interface.dll");
    ...
}
```

Где `my_super_dxgi_interface.dll` может статически линковаться с библиотекой/интерфейсом `DXGI`.

Answer (score 2):

`dxgi.lib` - это статическая библиотека *импорта* из dll. То бишь она сделана для возможности прилинковать `dxgi.dll` без наличия этой самой dll.

DXGI поддерживается начиная с Windows Vista. Кроме того, для Windows Vista доступно обновление Platform Update, устанавливающее компоненты DXGI и DirectX11, соответствующие Windows 7.